# How to extract data from a list of json in AWS athena

Tags: json, amazon-athena

I am new in Athena and I want to extract data from a json that has a list in his body. The file looks like that:

```
{"period": "082021/1","records":[{"date_income": "082021/1","cuit": "27365433157","cbu": "4530000800012453517105","amount_credit": "1.40","amount_income": "1.00","account_type": 1}]}
```

I need the data into the field "records", for example the "date_income", "cuit", "cbu" and the others...

The metadata of the table are:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `tax_sircreb`(
  `period` string,
  `records` array<string>)
PARTITIONED BY (
    `dt` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
    'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
    's3://dl-user/user/landing/sircreb/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'classification'='json')
```

Thanks

Comment: I need the data separated in diferent columns:

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for this problem:

```
SELECT period,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.account_type') AS account_type,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.cuit') AS cuit,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.date_income') AS date_income,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.cbu') AS cbu,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.amount_credit') AS amount_credit,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.amount_income') AS amount_income,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.currency_type') AS currency_type,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.crc') AS crc,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.registry_type') AS registry_type,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.number_movements') AS number_movements,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.operation_code') AS operation_code,
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(objetos, '$.devolution_id') AS devolution_id,
       dt
FROM(
        WITH dataset AS (
        SELECT
            period,
            records,
            dt
        FROM "schema"."tax_sircreb"
    )
        SELECT period, objetos, dt FROM dataset
        CROSS JOIN UNNEST(records) as t(objetos)
    )
```

Thanks to my partner who found it!